# Checking to see if a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is the bottom part of a form on a site that I have. Everything worked fine prior to adding the TOS agreement checkbox. Now, regardless of if the box is checked, it alerts the user that they must check the box. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<input type='checkbox' value='yes' name='tosagree' id='tosagree'> <p>I have read and agree to the privacy policy and terms of use found on this site.</p>
            <input type='submit' id='submit' name='submit' value='submit'><br /><br />
    </form>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function validateForm()
{
var asking=document.forms["form"]["asaskingprice"].value,
reasons=document.forms["form"]["asreasons"].value,
timelines=document.forms["form"]["astimelines"].value,
sources=document.forms["form"]["assources"].value,
tos=document.forms["form"]["tosagree"].value;
if (asking==null || asking=="")
  {
  alert("Asking price must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (reasons==null || reasons=="")
  {
  alert("reasons must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (timelines==null || timelines=="")
  {
  alert("timelines must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (sources==null || sources=="")
  {
  alert("sources must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
if (document.forms["form"]["tosagree"].Checked!=true)
  {
  alert("You must agree to the terms of service");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The powers that be removed the Too Localized close option :(

Comment: @JoeFrambach http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185105/133242 ...I'm trying to figure out exactly how to close this one.

Answer (score 5):

The correct attribute name is `checked`, not `Checked`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-checked

Comment: Thanks, I was following an example from another stackoverflow question and it was written as Checked.

Comment: @KyleVan link, please?

Answer (score 0):

You can just grab that sucker by its id like so:

```
var tos = document.getElementById('tosagree');

if (tos.checked) {
    //return true
}
```